# Windows Server 2012 website PORT

Tags: port, windows-server-2012

I am trying to use port 7777 for my dns web hosted site but i seem not to be able to connect to the website when i do that. It tries to log into my router? It brings up the user name and password to input to enter my router webpage.

If i use the default 80 port then my website comes up without a problem.

I have added the port to my routers port forwarding table with the servers IP both 80 and 7777 port (but not at the same time).

I've changed my bindings to use port 7777 in IIS manager.

I am also using No-Ip.com for my IP change (if it ever does).

How can i change the default port 80 to a custom port number without it trying to log into my router when i input my domain name url?

The no-ip settings i have to choose from is:

[image: no-ip 1]
or Port 80 Redirect?
[image: no-ip2]
Not sure if that's the problem or not but if i change it to 7777 for Port Redirect it still does not work and changes my domain name from www.xxxxxx.com to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:7777 which doesn't look nice.

My routers port settings:
[image: netgear]

Comment: You need to forward port 7777 to the IP that has the website. There are already a million answers on how to do this. Not even worth a downvote.

Comment: @ppumkin: I have added the port to my routers port forwarding table with the servers IP both 80 and 7777 port (but not at the same time).

Comment: Your tagging is a little misleading, what version of windows *exactly* are you using?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Windows Server 2012 but it seems to have the same setup as Win Server 2008 R2 from what i can tell.

Comment: Ye- fantastic so what is the problem?

Comment: @ppumkin: When i change the port to 7777. Change the port fowarding to 7777 for the server ip in my router and then visit the web site of my domain name my routers login box comes up.... It should go to the IIS 8 default website like it was doing on port 80.

Comment: Yes - because port 7777 was not forwarded to the correct place.  Sounds like a crap router to me.

Comment: Look- Nobody can be bothered any more to write a "how to diagnose port forwarding issues" any more OK. It is obvious there is a problem with the port forwarding hardware. You are doing the right thing- there is nothing special about it. Did you power down and up the router?

Comment: @ppumkin: Its a Netgear 6300 router [http://www.netgear.com/R6300]. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @ppumkin; JourneymanGeek: Updated OP.

Comment: Umm - Right so you just need to forward PORT 80(incomming to router) -> PORT 7777(incomming to webserver)  (problem solved) 5 bux

Comment: @ppumkin: How would i port 80 to 7777 in my router? That's not possible? It only has a range from xx-xx for port.

Comment: @ppumkin: Updated OP again with netgear port settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your router to listen to incoming web calls on port 80. Then forward it to your internal web server port 7777.

So your router will translate it from `(wan)80 => (lan)7777` (hiding your webserver behind your router essentially)

> http://www.myseupersite.com  (always uses port 80)
>
> https://www.myseupersite.com  (always uses secure port 443)

[image]

Maybe untick `use the smae port for internal port` ? not sure...

Comment: AH! Now i get that. Thanks ppumkin. Do i do the same things if i have another website hosted on the same server? As in **aaa.com->80->7777** and **bbb.com->81->7000**. I guess i would have to change 80 in no-ip to 81 for that domain name, right?

Comment: Yes- but if you use port 81 then the user HAS to enter mysite:81 - YOu can only every have 1 webserver(unless you have load balanced) or your  internal links point to that.

Comment: Yes, the **Use the same port range for Internal port** does need to be unchecked for the user to put their own port number in the box.

Comment: If you want to have many servers then you will need to place your own DNS server to resolve the DNS names to the correct internal virtual IP's (more advanced and out of scope)

Comment: Sorry i thought it was another port forward question. Glad to help with a decent solution.

Answer (score -1):

> changes my domain name from www.xxxxxx.com to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:7777

If your web server uses port 7777, that is what I would expect. You can get firewalls that can forward a request on one port to another, but it's less typical in cheap consumers routers.

Comment: boooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo -1 - he does not want to use http://blalalal:7777

Comment: No downvote needed @ppumkin. He replied to help. Thanks Joel!

Comment: That the problem with these guys with high rep +15000 they think they can use their bots to upvote while giving sh*t answers